# purpose of installing Oracle 11g R2 client

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, wamp

I am new to Oracle g database systems & have been using MYSQL DB as in WAMP for web app projects. But as requirements i need to shift to using PHP with Oracle 11g to develop my next web app.

what is the purpose of installing Oracle 11g R2 client & how is it different from Oracle 11g R2 server, also why is Oracle DBB installations available in these two above forms. Which one should i download & install in my windows system (hardware wise: plain/non-server machine) to practice out and integrate with WAMP server to build web apps to run PHP-Oracle connections ...

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to install the 11g server.  This will install the database itself and also the Client.

The Client is needed when you have a database instance running on a different server and you want to connect to it.

Comment: is there a free edition of 11g server for practice? Which one is it?

Comment: @Anirban All versions are free for practice and development.  You should use whatever version that will be used in production.